# google maps js API v3: recreate map with no memory leak / move map object to different div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, memory

I'm making what amounts to a slideshow pane to show different pages that needs to have 0 memory leaks. I want to show a google map of the area, but the div the map attaches to will periodically be replaced by different content, then return. I could theoretically move the div out of the pane and hide it, showing it again later, but that would be a last resort, as I feel attaching hidden divs to a page in the background really isn't a great idea. Is there a way to detach a map from a div and later reattach it, or is there a way to destroy a map in V3? I thought if you got rid of the div the map lived in it would destroy itself, but this test leaks memory just as much as not destroying the div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src = "/javascript/jquery.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        setTimeout(remMap,3000);
        setTimeout(mapempty,6000);
      }
    function mapempty(){
          $("body").append("<div id = 'map_canvas'></div>");
          initialize();
        }
    function remMap(){
          remove(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        }

        function remove(selection){
          selection.parentNode.removeChild(selection);
            }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

edit: it seems, contrary to what I read before, that google maps V3 does *not* support custom unloading; maps are only unloaded on page close, not when their divs are destroyed. It seems like attaching the div to the window hidden is the best bet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google maps V3 does *not* support custom unloading; maps are only unloaded on page close, not when their divs are destroyed.

V2 has GUnload